# how to assign to element of set of pairs through find iterator result

Tags: c++, iterator, constants, std-pair

I have a set of pairs and I want to change the second field of some pair that I want find first:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <set>

int main(){
  auto p=std::make_pair(2,3);
  std::set<std::pair<int,int>> s{p};
  auto it=s.find(p);
  it->second=5; // compilation error
  if(it!=s.end()) std::cout << it->second << '\n';
}
```

The above code fails to compile because it complains that the iterator result of find cannot be assigned to. However, I don't see why it is a const iterator.

What is wrong with the above, and how do I assign to the pair that the iterator result of find points to?

Comment: It is a set.  The items in the set cannot be modified.  To change something, delete it from the set, make a new different item, put that new item into the set.

Answer (score 0):

It's because set elements shouldn't be mutable, since the red-black tree that is used to implement it logically prevents us from screwing around with the actual nodes. Even without the implementation details, set elements shouldn't be mutable (as pointed out in one of the comments above), or else we could change `{2,3}` to `{2,2}`, which would be nonsensical.